# Id returned 1 exit status - File reading

Tags: c

I am moderately new to C and C++ and have an error in my code which I cannot find an answer for because when I find one answer more decide to surface. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* required for file operations */
FILE *file;

int main(void)
{
    double content;
    char *mode = "rt";
    int x = 1;
    const char *line();
    int lineInt = 1;
    const char *y;
    double data[1000];
    int i;
    double filename;

    if(x = 1)
    {
        scanf("%s", filename);
        file = fopen(&filename, mode);
        if (file == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        while (fgets (&line, 1000, file) != NULL);
        {
        lineInt == line;
        scanf(&line, "string", &data[lineInt]);
        line == line + 1;
        }
        fclose(file);  /* close the file prior to exiting the routine */
        for(i=1; i < line; i++);
        {
            printf("&d", data[i]);
        }
        fprint();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error "Id returned 1 exit status". I have looked at many sources on the web but still cannot find an answer, please help.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the whole error message? That would be very helpful.

Comment: `double filename;` you cannot enter a string into this variable. Try `char filename[100];` for example.

Comment: `const char *line();` is wrong. Try `char line[1000];`

Comment: `lineInt == line;` isn't going to work, and nor is `scanf(&line, "string", &data[lineInt]);`. I suggest you turn on all warnings, and work through the compiler errors and warnings one by one.

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of this line `for(i=1; i < line; i++);`

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of this line `while (fgets (&line, 1000, file) != NULL);`

Comment: Please go and read (and understand) a good C book or tutorial.

Comment: That's not the entire error message. You have the entire message on your screen, right in front of you. There is absolutely no excuse for not putting it in your question, so we have the information available. You're asking us to provide **free help** to solve **your problem**; you should make it as easy as possible for us to do so by giving us the details you already have about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors. I will list a few (see also the comments):

`double filename;` is wrong. Use `char filename[256];`

`const char *line();` is wrong. Use `char line[1000];`

`if (x=1)` This assigns 1 to `x`. Use `if (x==1)`

```
    while (fgets (&line, 1000, file) != NULL)
    {
        lineInt == line;
        scanf(&line, "string", &data[lineInt]);
        line == line + 1;
    }
    fclose(file);  /* close the file prior to exiting the routine */
```

You use `line` for two diferent purposes: to read from `stdin` with `scanf` and to read from the file with `fgets`. And remove the `;` as WeatherVane says. And the scanf call is garbage. Read the manual!

`for(i=1; i < line; i++);` Array indices start at 0, not 1.

`printf("&d"...` is wrong. Use `"%d"`.

`fprint();` without parameters is wrong. Your program will probably crash.

So about every line of your code has some eror. Please read a book on C. And turn all warnings on during compilation. You will get a lot.